# Azure Login with Powershell Script using PHP

Tags: php, azure, powershell

I have created powershell script for login in Azure. It works but what I want to do when login credential prompt open it should be open in existing browser.

Here is my code PHP + Powershell

```
Shell_Exec(powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File login.ps1 xyz@domain.onmicrosoft.com);
```

login.ps1

```
$getCredential = Get-Credential $args[0]
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $getCredential.UserName, $getCredential.Password
$Session = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $Credential 
Import-PSSession -Session $Session -AllowClobber
#Get-CsOnlineUser | ConvertTo-Json
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Now it shows below popup for login

[image]

Now I want this popup in existing web browser.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Also want to store that session for get users listing (Get-CsOnlineUser) via different PHP script.

Comment: You want a login pop up on the screen on which the user is browsing ?